# How to create a tolerance that makes all low values in the session become zero?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm making some calculations where I get values like number*e-17 , but i would like to make all those small values become zero.

Is there a way to make something like a tolerance that will change low values to zero in the whole program?
I'm using sympy btw.

many thanks,

Comment: This is an "XY problem": the correct solution in SymPy is to not make those small numbers to begin with. For that, use symbolic constants instead of numeric ones, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51428475)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `math.isclose` to test for closeness to zero, and set the values accordingly:

```
import math

value = 0 if math.isclose(value, 0) else value
```

[more details in python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html)